# How do I get the specific value from data attribute via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table containing records taken from a database. I have a button for each record which makes a dialogue box appear when clicked.

```
<img src="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>library/images/ui/buttons/delete.png" class="bookmark-delete" data-bookmark="<?php echo $array_bookmarks_for_manage['bookmark_id']; ?>" height="14" width="14" />
```

Each button is a graphic and has a data attribute attached to it containing the ID of each record.

I'm trying to get the value of a data attribute to appear in the dialogue box.

My Code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialogue").hide();
    $("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'bookmarks/delete/' + **$('.bookmark-delete').data('bookmark')**);
    $('.bookmark-delete').click(function(event) {
        $("#dialogue").css( { position:"absolute", top: event.pageY+15, left: event.pageX-315 });
        $("#dialogue").show();
    });
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $("#dialogue").hide();
    });
});
```

And this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialogue").hide();
    $("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'bookmarks/delete/' + **$(this).data('bookmark')**);
    $('.bookmark-delete').click(function(event) {
        $("#dialogue").css( { position:"absolute", top: event.pageY+15, left: event.pageX-315 });
        $("#dialogue").show();
    });
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $("#dialogue").hide();
    });
});
```

And also this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialogue").hide();
    $("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'bookmarks/delete/' + **$(this).attr('data-bookmark')**);
    $('.bookmark-delete').click(function(event) {
        $("#dialogue").css( { position:"absolute", top: event.pageY+15, left: event.pageX-315 });
        $("#dialogue").show();
    });
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $("#dialogue").hide();
    });
});
```

All with no joy; every attempt either results in "undefined" or the last record ID in the table.

Everything else works except the retrieval of the value on third line of each example, which I've emboldened for emphasis.

The dialogue box is positioned outside of and after the table:

```
    <div id="dialogue">
        <h3>Delete Bookmark</h3>
        <p>Do you want to delete this Bookmark?</p>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <ul class="buttons">
            <li><div id="button-link"><a class="button-link action" href="#">Delete</a></div></li>
            <li><div id="button-link"><a class="button-link" href="#close" id="close">Cancel</a></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="cleaner"></div>
    </div>
```

Also, here's a [JS Fiddle of what I have](http://jsfiddle.net/WayneSmallman/jFtEU/). Please be aware, that for some reason, the code doesn't work at all on JS Fiddle, even though everything but the ID works here locally.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post full html for the element with the data attribute.

Comment: `$(this)` in your second and third attempt refers to the window, it won't have a 'data-bookmark' attribute.

Comment: Kevin, I've made an edit to include the complete HTML.

Comment: Where is `a.action`? Is it part of the dialog?

Comment: Jack, that's correct. As I said, everything else is working, except the retrieval of the proper ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.bookmark-delete').click(function(event) {
var yourDataAtr =         $(this).attr("data-bookmark");
    });
```

and do whatever with your `yourDataAtr` value

Comment: Varun, as I explained in the opening post, that option doesn't work.

Comment: @WayneSmallman - this case cannot fail at all, provide your code on jsfiddle

Comment: Varun, I've tried placing the code in my own, but with no joy. I need to know what the final and complete code would look like.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var bookmarkid = $(this).data('bookmark');    
$("a.action").attr("href", base_url+'bookmarks/delete/'+bookmarkid);
```

in place of

```
$("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'bookmarks/delete/' + $(this).attr('data-bookmark'));
```

Comment: Jasse, as I explained in the opening post, that option doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
var data = $(".bookmark-delete").attr('data-bookmark');
```

and

```
var data = $(".bookmark-delete").data('bookmark');
```

return required value. And then use -

```
 $("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'bookmarks/delete/' + data);
```

Comment: Sachin, as I explained in the opening post, those two options don't work.